# Python datetime parse timezone (RFC3339)

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Currently I'm writing a small python application where I get a date of the following format ([RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)) from a webserver:

```
2016-01-29T20:00:00+01:00
```

I have to parse this date to a python datetime object and for this I would like to use the `datetime.strptime` method where I have to specify the format of the date but I don't know how to parse the timezone (+01:00) I tried with:

```
datetime.strptime(strDate, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

but this does not work. Can you please tell me which format string I have to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dateutil`, however, if you are using Python 3 it only works for 3.2 or 3.3. It also supports Python 2 on 2.6 and 2.7.

The solution I would suggest:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

string = "2016-01-29T20:00:00+01:00"

date = parse(string)
```

This will give you a datetime object like so:

```
Out[1]: 2016-01-29 20:00:00+01:00
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 29, 20, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```

If you'd like to know more, check dateutil [documentation](https://labix.org/python-dateutil).

Moreover, I believe the reason `strptime` doesn't work straight away here is due to that 'T' on your date string. It's not the format `strptime` expects. Luckily `dateutil` parse method works right out of the box to fix that string for you.

Answer (score 2):

Can you do this,

```
strDate = strDate.split('+')

datetime.strptime(strDate[0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

This will work for you

Comment: ...but discarding the timezone creates a [naive object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime). Presumably the OP wants an aware one.

Comment: Yaah i got this @Charles David's ans is ryt